# Replace many sybase tags in favour of sybase-ase and sqlanywhere

Tags: support, stack-overflow, tags, retag-request

The [sybase](/questions/tagged/sybase) tag is ambiguous, as Sybase has two quite distinct database products: [sybase-ase](/questions/tagged/sybase-ase) and [sqlanywhere](/questions/tagged/sqlanywhere). Many questions are not tagged correctly, because both Sybase products are literally just called "Sybase" by end users. But then it's kind of hard to determine the correct product in questions like this one here, which in turn leads to wrong answers and unnecessary discussions:

[How do I get just the Nth row of data from sybase?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3612379/how-do-i-get-just-the-nth-row-of-data-from-sybase)

In the above question, 2 of 3 answers are good answers for [sqlanywhere](/questions/tagged/sqlanywhere), when the OP is actually asking about [sybase-ase](/questions/tagged/sybase-ase).

But in principle, tagging these questions simply with [sybase](/questions/tagged/sybase) is about as wrong as not caring whether you're asking a [sql-server](/questions/tagged/sql-server) or an [ms-access](/questions/tagged/ms-access) question and just blindly tagging it as [microsoft](/questions/tagged/microsoft)... Or you might not care about if something is about [ios](/questions/tagged/ios) or [osx](/questions/tagged/osx) and just tag it as [apple](/questions/tagged/apple)

How could this be improved? Should there be some warning rules attached to certain tags, e.g. when you tag your question with [sybase](/questions/tagged/sybase), then you *should* also chose one of [sybase-ase](/questions/tagged/sybase-ase) and [sqlanywhere](/questions/tagged/sqlanywhere)? Or should the [sybase](/questions/tagged/sybase) tag be completely removed and merged into the any of the other two?